# ¿cómo agregar transición a placeholder en pantallas pequeñas?

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap

Espero que estén bien!

Lo que quiero lograr es que si tengo un texto demasiado largo en un `placeholder`, en pantallas pequeñas se muestra hasta cierto punto.

Ejemplo: INGRESE LA FECHA DE NACIMIENTO,(AÑO/MES/DIA)

Y en pantalla pequeña: INGRESE LA FECHA DE NACÍ

Como puedo agregar un efecto donde el texto del `placeholder` haga una transición que permita leer todo el texto. (que el texto vaya de derecha a izquierda  y un efecto suave)

Comment: Cuando dices pantalla chicas (o chica) significa pequeña, en una pantalla pequeña? Y otra pregunta, donde pones ejemplo eso tiene que ser texto diciendo de introducir la fecha y luego abajo el actual placeholder?

Answer (score 2):

Lo que se puede hacer es una animación al placeholder para mostrarlo arriba del input así.

```css
label {
  margin:20px 0;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
  
span {
  padding:10px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  transition: 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1);
  opacity:0.5;
}

input {
  padding:10px;
}

input:focus + span, input:not(:placeholder-shown) + span {
  opacity:1;
  transform: scale(0.75) translateY(-100%) translateX(-30px);
}

/* For IE Browsers*/
input:focus + span, input:not(:-ms-input-placeholder) + span {
  opacity:1;
  transform: scale(0.75) translateY(-100%) translateX(-30px);
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input placeholder=" ">
  <span>Placeholder Text</span>
</label>
```

La cuestión es ir jugando en la linea `transform: scale(0.75) translateY(-100%) translateX(-30px);`  y moverlo para donde quieras.